# Is there some way to retrieve/redisplay :echon output?

Tags: highlight, color, echo, debugging, highlighting

I want to create a multi-color enabled debug-print command. As far I know, the only way to print multi-color messages in Vim is:

```
echohl Macro | echon "Hi" | echohl Statement | 
     \ echon " There!" | echohl None
```

I plan to utilize this technique. However there's a main drawback of `echon` — it **isn't stored in *any* message history**, not even in the single-past message recall command **g<**. I think that this limitation undermines the purpose of the *debug*-print function/command…

Is there some way to print multi-color and have the message remembered in some generally available history? So that the user of a plugin can restore the last messages and read them (because IMO it's mostly the case that when the user does something in Vim he out of an inertia enters 1-2 commands too much and they cancel the messages)?

Comment: Please post an answer with what you implemented in https://asciinema.org/a/357950 (from your comments on a now deleted answer.) Thanks!